# Elastic search river mongodb not indexing documents

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I will detail what I have done

**mongodb**

version - 2.6.5

start command used
sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet myreplicaset --rest --httpinterface

Replica set started by rs.initiate()
Checked status using rs.status()

Authentication disabled in mongod.conf.
Only one replica member, primary member only, oplog.rs getting updated.

Mongodb db - elasticindex
mongodb collection - elastictype

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("548568cfc8e2e59210e94c00"),
   "country": "nepal",
   "state": "katmandu"
}
```

**Elastic search**

ES version - 1.4.0
Plugin river-mongodb - 2.0.5
Plugin mapper-attachments - 2.4.2

**Created mapping in ES**

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/elasticindex -d '
{
 "mappings" : {
  "elastictype" : { 
   "properties" : {
    "country" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "state" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
   }
  }
 }
}';
```

**Created river in ES**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
      "db": "elasticindex", 
      "collection": "elastictype"
    }, 
    "index": {
      "name": "elasticindex", 
      "type": "elastictype" 
    }
  }'
```

**Restart ES**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start


tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

gives like this

```
[2014-12-09 14:38:02,675][INFO ][transport                ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/10.3.0.53:9301]}
[2014-12-09 14:38:02,704][INFO ][discovery                ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] elasticsearch/Fcu1-KFNStSTA0BoENO5Cw
[2014-12-09 14:38:06,484][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] new_master [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton][Fcu1-KFNStSTA0BoENO5Cw][qbadmin-desktop][inet[/10.3.0.53:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-12-09 14:38:06,518][INFO ][http                     ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/10.3.0.53:9201]}
[2014-12-09 14:38:06,518][INFO ][node                     ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] started
[2014-12-09 14:38:07,574][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Lady Jacqueline Falsworth Crichton] recovered [8] indices into cluster_state
[2014-12-09 14:38:08,992][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Starting river mongodb
[2014-12-09 14:38:09,094][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.5-SNAPSHOT] - hash[${build] - time[2014-11-28T12:36:31Z]
[2014-12-09 14:38:09,094][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] starting mongodb stream. options: secondaryreadpreference [false], drop_collection [false], include_collection [], throttlesize [5000], gridfs [false], filter [null], db [elasticindex], collection [elastictype], script [null], indexing to [elasticindex]/[elastictype]
[2014-12-09 14:38:09,094][INFO ][river.mongodb.util       ] setRiverStatus called with mongodb - RUNNING
```

I am stuck in this issue for few days, thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT**
When running `db.currentOp()` 
Got this result

```
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
```

When running `db.currentOp(true)`
Got the below result

```
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "opid" : 0,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "signalProcessingThread",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85cb370700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 1,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "DataFileSync",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85cab6f700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 11,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "insert",
            "ns" : "local.startup_log",
            "insert" : {

            },
            "client" : "0.0.0.0:0",
            "desc" : "initandlisten",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85ccc4bb40",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(0),
                    "W" : NumberLong(585)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(0),
                    "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 3,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "journal",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85c9b6d700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(13553),
                    "W" : NumberLong(11916)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(2889157),
                    "W" : NumberLong(1731)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 16,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "rsSyncNotifier",
            "threadId" : "0x7f7b8c142700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 21,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "elasticindex",
            "query" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "orderby" : {
                    "$natural" : -1
                }
            },
            "client" : "0.0.0.0:0",
            "desc" : "rsMgr",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85ac366700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(0),
                    "W" : NumberLong(972)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 20,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "rsGhostSync",
            "threadId" : "0x7f7b8b941700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 5,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "snapshotthread",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85aeb6b700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 290,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "test.system.indexes",
            "query" : {
                "expireAfterSeconds" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            },
            "client" : "0.0.0.0:0",
            "desc" : "TTLMonitor",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85ad368700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(40),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 7,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "clientcursormon",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85ae36a700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(69845),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(26680),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 8,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "RangeDeleter",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85acb67700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 12,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "websvr",
            "threadId" : "0x7f81a1b64700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 294,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {
                "replSetGetStatus" : 1,
                "forShell" : 1
            },
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:53512",
            "desc" : "conn1",
            "threadId" : "0x7f85ccc48700",
            "connectionId" : 1,
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 17,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "rsBackgroundSync",
            "threadId" : "0x7f7b8c943700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 18,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "SyncSourceFeedbackThread",
            "threadId" : "0x7f7b8b140700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {

                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 19,
            "active" : false,
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "local.replset.minvalid",
            "query" : {

            },
            "desc" : "rsSync",
            "threadId" : "0x7f818494f700",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(0),
                    "W" : NumberLong(79),
                    "r" : NumberLong(276),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "R" : NumberLong(0),
                    "W" : NumberLong(1),
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It says it's running. So what are you actually stuck on? Your index is empty?

Comment: Yes, my index is empty when I run curl -XGET localhost:9200/elasticindex/elastictype/_search

Comment: did you check if the version of your river is compatible with your elasticsearch version?

Comment: I am using 2.0.5 river plugin, that means master. checked with version compatible table https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/

Comment: can you try to check your running mongodb processes? Check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) for more info

Comment: I have added the result from db.currentOp by editing the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66539/discussion-between-rajeesh-v-and-eliasah).

Comment: River worked with another configuration 
mongodb 2.2.4
elastic search - 0.90.13
ES river - 1.6.6
ES mapper - 1.9.0

Comment: The same example worked when I downgrade elastic search to 1.3.5, river plugin 2.0.2, mapper 2.3.2, no change to mongodb(2.6.5)